# Working with multiple Silverlight versions

Tags: .net, silverlight, multiple-versions

I have Silverlight 4 Tools for VS2010 installed for developing Prism and Silverlight 4 apps with VS2010.
I am accessing a site to watch videos that needs Silverlight client version 5. When i install it, my Silverlight 4 apps break (XAML designer window shows exceptions and runtime error saying no matching runtime found). The only solution i know of is to uninstall both Silverlight 4 and 5 and then re-install 4. What are the workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the silverlight project in visual studio and go to the properties page, there is a combo box to choose the Target Silverlight Version in the Silverlight tab. From there you should be able to choose SL 4 or 5.

Comment: In the Target Silverlight Version drop-down, i see only two options - Silverlight 3 and 4 but not 5. Now, why is that?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed both Silverlight 5 Toolkit and Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio from Silverlight.net? http://www.silverlight.net/downloads

Comment: I haven't installed Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio because i do not have VS2010 with Service Pack 1 as the prerequisites state. What is Silverlight 5 SDK?

Comment: I edited my last post, I meant to say Silverlight 5 Toolkit instead of SDK. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: I have VS2010 version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. What i dont understand is that i already have the Silverlight 4 runtime installed (with the tools installation) and it tells me that Silverlight 4 runtime is not found.

Comment: Hmm strange..I would recommend uninstalling all of your Silverlight runtime/tools, updating VS2010 to Service Pack 1, and then reinstalling Silverlight 4 SDK / Tools for Visual Studio, and then reinstalling Silverlight 5 Toolkit / Tools for Visual Studio